# MS Access Form Debugging

Tags: ms-access

Hello I have a pretty intricate Access database. I just jumped on this project and have never used Access. I have a form that is generating a value entry popup when I try to run it and it shouldn't be. The problem is the form is trying to access a column of a table which has been changed recently. I just have no idea where to find the query or what exactly is trying to access that column. Any help greatly appreciated. I am using Access 2016 also.

Comment: How intricate is your form? Are there lots of subforms? Bound controls? You'll likely need to scan through their record sources to find the culprit. Also check the form's "Filter" or "Order By" properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like the problem inst actually your form but the query your form is based upon.

This may be a separate query or a query built in your forms record source.

Go to your form in design view. Open up the property sheet. (Under design tab) make sure the dropdown box has Form Selected and look at the Record Source.

The record source may state a query name, In which case you should remove the field/replace the field with another in that query.

Or if it says something along the lines of "Select ......" then just alter that query to not have the field you have removed/renamed and the problem should go away.

However it is worth noting that if you have sub forms it could be the record source of one of those.